# No getting AddtoBundle Popup in 2013 at the first time creation of a Component

Tags: event-system

I am having below event, when this below event is firing I am not getting AddToBundle Popup

```cs
 EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, LoadEventArgs>(AddXmlSpaceForContentPorter, EventPhases.Processed);
```

Is there any relation between the `LoadEvent`  of the Component and AddtoBundle Popup. Why it's restricting in this case?

Comment: What code are you executing in your `AddXmlSpaceForContentPorter` method exactly?

Comment: I can't see the relationship between a Component LOAD event and the bundle popup - does it work if you remove this event?

Comment: I just have added one line system.Threading.sleep(1000) inside AddXmlSpaceForContentPorter() to just sleep for 1 sec while exceuting..........But AddtoBundle popup is not coming....can you please tell why AddtoBundle popup is not coming when the exceution of time is more than 1 sec for component loadevent...

Comment: But when i remove the line system.threading.sleep(1000) ....then its working fine....

Comment: @Target: If I'm not wrong, it was working earlier too. But problem is  you have configured your events dll and haven't restarted the services.

Comment: I have restarted the services too...only what i noticed is when the execution time is more than 1 sec for component load event ..i am facing this issue...

Comment: Was this solved? The default behavior for Components based on Schemas with a indirect Workflow association (basically the require approval setting) is to prompt the Add to Bundle Pop-up as it's saved (so most likely not *load* as @Nuno suggested).